# Google drive webhook add/modify/remove file

Tags: google-drive-api, webhooks, drive

I would like to know how to know when you receive a webhook if it is a new file added to google drive, a file modified or a file removed.

```
@POST
@Path("/webhook")
public void webhook(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    Credential credential = initFlow().loadCredential("user");
    Drive service = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();

    String pageToken = GDrive.savedPageToken;

    while (pageToken != null) {
        ChangeList changes = service.changes().list(pageToken).execute();

        for (Change change : changes.getChanges()) {

            if (!change.getFile().getMimeType().equalsIgnoreCase("application/vnd.google-apps.folder")) {
                //IGNORE FOLDERS
                Log.info("Removed file: "+ change.toString());
            }
        }
        if (changes.getNewStartPageToken() != null) {
            GDrive.savedPageToken = changes.getNewStartPageToken();
        }
        pageToken = changes.getNextPageToken();
    }
    response.setStatus(200);
}
```

I'm just interested in file changes, so I ignore application/vnd.google-apps.folder.

How I can differentiate from these?

1. Case that file is added.
2. Case that file is modified.
3. Case that file is removed permanently.

Comment: Do you have a sample response, where change was detected?

Comment: In the response there are only a few headers and no one gives information, since there could be multiple files changes at once: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push#receiving-notifications